# How to override the default text in MATLAB

Tags: templates, matlab

In MATLAB, when you click File -> New -> Function M-File, you get a file with the following contents:

```
function [ output_args ] = Untitled( input_args )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


end
```

Is it possible to override this behaviour, and specify your own text?

(The motivation is that I'm trying to persuade my colleagues to document their m-files more thoroughly, and having default text for them to fill in might encourage them.)

Comment: Which version of MATLAB is this?

Comment: @Jacob: It works in `R2008b` (and later), but not in `R2007b`.  I haven't got `R2008a` handy to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't even know File->New->Function did that.

The way I solved the issue was to write a function that you call via

```
>>newFunction myNewFunctionName
```

It then

1. pops up an inputdlg window, which asks the user for the synopsis and the H1 line and allows to already write help to explain input and output arguments. There, the user also selects whether myNewFunctionName is a function or a class in order to choose the right header and 'function call'
2. checks whether a function of the same name exists already
3. asks for a folder to save the function, and
4. opens the function in the editor

The header is set up so that it's easy to fill in info about input and output. It also automatically lists the username of the person who created the file as well as the date and the Matlab version.

**EDIT**
For new classes, the template function automatically makes sure that they subclass my general superclass that implements methods such as 'help' (which calls `doc(class(obj))` )

Now if the template functionwould also write the algorithm part of the function, it would be really convenient. :)

**EDIT2**
[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27132)'s a link to the function on the file exchange.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a novel solution.  Maybe a function-writer GUI could implement this nicely.  I feel it's important not to underestimate the laziness/hatred of documentation factor though.  It still seems more effort than clicking File->New->Function-with-stuff-written-for-me.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: the function is called as 'codeTemplate myNewFunction' and then asks the user for the additional input via inputdlg. I require the H1-line so that there's some minimum documentation

Comment: @Richie Cotton: I updated my answer a bit. I don't think this is anymore involved than clicking File->New->Function, though you could skip the step where the dialog window pops up. However, other than requiring the H1 line, it is actually less work than the Matlab default, since you don't need to replace 'untitled' with 'myFunctionName' everywhere.

Comment: @Jonas: Have you considered to put your function on File Exchange?

Comment: @yuk: not till now. I will add a link to it once it has passed review

Comment: @Jonas: I'm opting for a stripped down version of this.  I like the idea of a function autogenerating content.  However, since you don't always want to write the documentation immediately when you create the file, asking all these questions might be too instrusive.  I'll post my function to the file exchange once I've road-tested it.

Comment: Another good idea I've just had is to create a shortcut that calls the function, so the file can be opened with a single click.  As I said, never underestimate laziness ...

Comment: @Richie Cotton: This is an excellent idea! As you'll see from my function, adding help for input and output is optional, but the H1 line is something you should be able to write for every function right away. After all, when you start a new function, you should have an idea what it does.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making your own default m-file template, called `default.m` for example, and placing it in a folder on the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/path.shtml) where your colleagues can access it. You should then set the file to be read-only. Your colleagues can then execute any one of the following commands in the MATLAB Command Window when they want to create a new function m-file:

```
open default.m
open('default.m')
edit default.m
edit('default.m')
```

The functions [OPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/open.html) and [EDIT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/edit.html) will open a file in the MATLAB Editor. Since the file `default.m` is read-only, if anyone tries to save over it they will get a dialog box warning them as such and asking them to save to a new file (or overwrite it). That should keep them from accidentally modifying the template.

Comment: @gnovice: I like that this isn't intrusive, and that it's easy to do.  It does have the disadvantage of requiring the user to manually fill in everything though.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through all text files starting from matlabroot folder, but could not find that template. Seems it's hard-coded, which is weird.

I like Jonas [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554718/how-to-override-the-default-text-in-matlab/2554976#2554976). As my two cents, you can download a function (not mine) doing similar things with some customization from [here](http://msbs.ca/matlab/?p=10).

Comment: @yuk: That second link gets blocked by my internet filter, claiming to be malware; are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @Richie: Opened ok from my work and home. It's just a Matlab blog: http://msbs.ca/matlab/

Comment: Must just be an overzealous filter at work; it opens fine at home.  The use of `com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices.newDocument(str)` to put the template directly into the editor is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

After more pondering, I've come up with a solution that I'm happy with, combining Jonas' and gnovice's answers.  It's a function that creates a new m-file (with template documentation), and opens it in the editor.  It is available from the Matlab Central [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27225-generate-a-new-function-m-file-with-documentation).